# tkinter Entry and Radiobutton variables not updating

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, radio-button, tkinter-entry

I'm using python 3.8 on PyCharm.
I want to create a GUI in which I can choose between making a directory or a file and give it a name.
Here is just the function

```
def ask_add():
    global aroot
    aroot = Tk()
    aroot.asking = True
    name_var = StringVar()
    aroot.geometry('500x400')
    aroot.title('OOS')
    aroot.config(bg='black')
    # name label
    name_label = Label(aroot, text='Name:', bg='black', fg='#00ff00', font=16)
    name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
    # name entry
    name_entry = Entry(aroot, bg='black', fg='#00ff00', insertbackground='#00ff00', textvariable=name_var, width=40)
    name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    # type label
    type_label = Label(aroot, text='Type:', fg='#00ff00', bg='black', font=16)
    type_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    # type radio buttons
    type_var = StringVar()
    file_option = Radiobutton(aroot, bg='black', fg='#00ff00', text='File', font=16, variable=type_var, value='File', activebackground='#00ff00', activeforeground='black')
    file_option.grid(row=1, column=1)
    dir_option = Radiobutton(aroot, bg='black', fg='#00ff00', text='Dir', font=16, variable=type_var, value='Dir', activebackground='#00ff00', activeforeground='black')
    dir_option.grid(row=2, column=1)
    # create dir / file
    create_button = Button(aroot, text='Create', bg='black', fg='#00ff00', font=18, activebackground='#00ff00', activeforeground='black', command=lambda: add(name_var.get(), type_var.get()))
    create_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

    while aroot.asking:
        aroot.update()
```

and here is the *add()* function

```
def add(n, t): # name, type
    global aroot
    aroot.asking = False
    aroot.destroy()
    print(n, t)
    if t == 'File':
        p = subprocess.Popen(f'echo.>{n}', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        err = str(p.stderr.read().decode())
        if err != '':
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message=err)
    else: # t == Dir
        p = subprocess.Popen(f'md {n}', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        err = str(p.stderr.read().decode())
        if err != '':
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message=err)
    update() # updates a window that displays directories
```

I expect the script to pass the *name_var* and the *type_var* to the function *add()*, but these variables don't update (their value remains '') when I type in the Entry or click the Radiobuttons, so the function *add()* cannot create any file or directory.
I also tried to print the variables in the while loop

```
    while aroot.asking:
        print(name_var.get(), type_var.get())
        aroot.update()
```

but their value remains *''*. 
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: The indentation in your code is broken. It's unclear whether all of the code is in side `ask_add1`, or only part of the code.

Comment: Had also tried that, but nothing changed

Comment: @Obertuba: Works for me as it should. You use `aroot.destroy()` therefore i assume your problem is: [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem just by changing the value of *type_var* whenever I click a radiobutton using `command=lambda: type_var.set(*my value*)`.

```
file_option = Radiobutton(aroot, bg='black', fg='#00ff00', text='File', font=16, variable=type_var, value='File', activebackground='#00ff00', activeforeground='black', command=lambda: type_var.set('File'))
file_option.grid(row=1, column=1)
dir_option = Radiobutton(aroot, bg='black', fg='#00ff00', text='Dir', font=16, variable=type_var, value='Dir', activebackground='#00ff00', activeforeground='black', command=lambda: type_var.set('Dir'))
dir_option.grid(row=2, column=1)
```